# SRID Transformation in PostGIS giving inaccurate transformation

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, proj, prj

I am trying to make a transformation in PostGIS from ESPG 4326 to ESPG 5247. The problem is that when the data is imported into ArcMap 10.7 it is clearly in the wrong place (by about 2.5km). I have projected the same layer using ArcMap 10.7 and it overlays the original (ESPG 4326) perfectly. I have noticed both the proj (.prj) files are different (see below). If I copy and paste the ArcMap proj file into the PostGIS version of the same layer it works so it must be something to do with the proj file.

See the code below.

SQL Code Used to make the transformation

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN geom
TYPE Geometry(POINT, 5247)
USING ST_Transform(geom, 5247);
```

ArcGIS proj file

```
PROJCS["GDBD2009_GEORSO",GEOGCS["GCS_GDBD2009",DATUM["D_GDBD2009",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Rectified_Skew_Orthomorphic_Natural_Origin"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.99984],PARAMETER["Azimuth",53.31580995],PARAMETER["Longitude_Of_Center",115.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",4.0],PARAMETER["XY_Plane_Rotation",53.13010235415598],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Below is the PostGIS proj file (this is the same as the srtext column in the spatial_ref_sys table

````
PROJCS["GDBD2009 / Brunei BRSO",GEOGCS["GDBD2009",DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_Brunei_Darussalam_2009",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","1056"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5246"]],PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",4],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",115],PARAMETER["azimuth",53.31580995],PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",53.13010236111111],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.99984],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5247"]]```



---

I went through all the parameters in both projections and they seem to be the same. From what I can tell from looking online, the Hotline Oblique Mercator is the same as the Rectified Skew Orthomorphic Natural Origin projection. 

I added an x,y column in the attributes tables and even though they they do not overlay on the map they both calculate the same coordinates. Also when I drop both of them into QGIS, they overlay as expected. So I'm guessing it is something to do with the way ArcMap is reading the prj file that was exported from PostgreSQL. While the parameters are all the same, they seem to be bundled together differently.
````

Comment: what versions of PostGIS, ArcMap and proj are you using?

Comment: ArcMap 10.8.1 PostGIS Bundle 3 for PostgreSQL x64 12

Comment: I am working via pgAdmin4 4.24   Not sure about proj. Sorry.

Comment: As far as I can see, the PostGIS definition agrees with the official EPSG one. Is it possible that ArcMap does not support the `Hotine_Oblique_Mercator` projection? Does it work if you copy the .prj in the other direction?